# Mover span com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um span mover quando coloco o mouse sobre um botão, e quando tiro o mouse ele volta para posiçao inicial. Estou usando a classe animate do jquery, o unico problema é que, quando eu passo o mouse diversas vezes sobre o botão ele continua executando a animação varias vezes. O que queria fazer é, quando eu passar o mouse por cima e sair, caso passe por cima novamente a função continue de onde o span estiver.

Esse é meu código:

`$("button#icone-seta-move").mouseover(function(){
    $("span#icone-seta").animate({"margin-left":"207px", "opacity":"1"},400);
});
$("button#icone-seta-move").mouseout(function(){
    $("span#icone-seta").animate({"margin-left":"190px", "opacity":"0"},400);
});`

Comment: Já tentou `$("span#icone-seta").stop().animate(...)` ?

Comment: O problema nao é parar a animação, eu quero que ela continue de onde parou, por exemplo o :hover no css por exemplo: se vc vai mudar a cor de um botao e coloca pra mudar da branco pro preto em 1s. se vc colocar o mouse e tirar varias vezes, ele sempre vai continuar a transição de onde ela parou.

Comment: Consegui aqui valew usei .hover() do jquery, fiz assim: $("button#icone-seta-move").hover();